# Low sound volume with Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (ALC3227) in HP 15-BS576TX laptop

Tags: alsa, hp, intel-hd

I have a new laptop HP-15-BS576TX which has this Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio.

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
```

**EDIT: I have submitted a bug report to Ubuntu Bug Tracking:** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1737614

The laptop sound works perfectly fine in Windows 10 with realtek drivers. However, in Linux, the volume is quite low, that I've to scroll the volume slider above 100% mark to the maximum to get some sound. I suspect the sound is not coming from all speakers (perhaps subwoofer exist for this model). Details about the audio hardware are below:

**lspci -vvv | grep -A 40 -i audio**:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 832b
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 131
Region 0: Memory at b1328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Region 4: Memory at b1300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Address: 00000000fee00358  Data: 0000
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

**lsmod | grep '^snd' | column -t :**

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152   1
snd_hda_codec_realtek  94208   1
snd_hda_codec_generic  73728   1   snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_skl            77824   0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        49152   1   snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384   1   snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768   1   snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_hda_ext_core       24576   1   snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_match      16384   1   snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core           229376  1   snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           20480   1   snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384   1   snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          40960   6
snd_hda_codec          126976  4   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek

snd_hda_core           81920   7   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480   1   snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304   8   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_core
snd_seq_midi           16384   0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384   1   snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768   1   snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536   2   snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384   3   snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768   2   snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920   25          snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
```

**head -n 1 /proc/asound/card0/codec* :**

```
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: Realtek ALC3227

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#2 <==
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

I have gone through Linux kernel sources ALSA and Snd-HDA lists and unable to find any optimizations for this laptop.
http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.3/source/Documentation/sound/hd-audio/models.rst
http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.3/source/Documentation/sound/alsa-configuration.rst

Comment: +1 for `| column -t` pipe.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to Ubuntu BTS, regarding this problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1737614

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Edit the file below:

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

And make sure that the `load-module module udev-detect` line looks like this:

```
load-module module-udev-detect ignore_dB=1
```

and restart the PulseAudio server:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Then retest.

Links:

1. The [Arch Linux wiki on pulseaudio troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#No_sound_below_a_volume_cutoff) on no sound below specific thresholds.

Comment: I tried adding ignore_dB=1 and restarted, still, there is no gain in volume. :(